# Error looping through an array with a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with this code for a long time but i wont't compile. I am trying to loop through the array with a pointer. Any thoughts on what might be wrong? Thanks!

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main(){

   string texts[] = {"one", "two", "three"};

   string *pTexts = texts;

   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(texts)/sizeof(string); i++)
   {
     cout << pTexts[i] << " " << endl;
     pTexts++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `pTexts[i]` does in conjunction with `pTexts++`?

Comment: Use indexing or pointer arithmetic, but not both.

Comment: "but i wont't compile" - Read the error message... if unclear, google it.

Comment: You need `#include <string>`

Answer (score 3):

You increment both `i` and `pTexts`.  Remove the `pTexts++;`